# Symfony2 - github - publishing packagist

Tags: symfony, github, composer-php, packagist

A main problem is that triggers error on composer require package.

I'm trying to publish Symfony package using packagist. I have already commited with composer.json:

```
{
    "name" : "vendor/package",
    "description" : "Some description",
    "type" : "symfony-bundle",
    "authors" : [{
    "name" : "Name",
    "email" : "example@example.com"
    }],
    "keywords" : [
    "keywords"
    ],
    "license" : [
    "MIT"
    ],
    "require": {
    "php": ">=5.2.0",
    "twig": "~1.18"
    },
    "autoload" : {
    "psr-0" : {
        "Vendor\\Package" : ""
    }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "target-dir" : "Vendor/Package",
    "repositories" : [{
    }]
}
```

On packagist binding and successfully shows package vendor/package, so I have only dev-master:

```
"vendor/package": "dev-master"
```

Here is problem when trying require package in Symfony 2.6 and throws:

```
composer require "vendor/package": "dev-master"                                                                      
  [InvalidArgumentException]                                                                                                                  
  Could not find package dev-master at any version for your minimum-stability (stable). Check the package spelling or your minimum-stability
```

Comment: "minimum-stability (stable)".  Problem is with versioning which is done via tags on github. Either release stable version on github. Or change stability requirements. You have to set minimum stability to dev in "root" composer.json. In your case your symfony applications composer.json.

Comment: Yes but it's mistake in composer.json file. Fixed in my answer. Thank you for tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed with this composer.json and add into Github tags and branches version such as 1.0.0, then require version 1.0.* or dev-master.

```
{
    "name" : "vendor/package",
    "description" : "Description",
    "type" : "symfony-bundle",
    "authors" : [{
    "name" : "Name",
    "email" : "example@example.com"
    }],
    "keywords" : [  
    "keywords"
    ],
    "license" : [
    "MIT"
    ],
    "require": {
    "php": ">=5.2.0",
    "symfony/console": "~2.0"
    },
    "autoload" : {
    "psr-0" : {
        "vendor\\package" : ""
    }
    },
    "target-dir" : "vendor/package"
}
```